# C# Console.Application - How can I read an input / key press without pressing enter?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to make an application that let's the user search for a file.

I know how to actually write the code for the file search in the user's computer,

but I want that the results that are found would be printed out "live" / while the user pressing the

keys, entering the file name.

---

Therefore my question, how to do something **like** Console.ReadLine(); / Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

But without "forcing" the user to press enter to "send" the results to that executed code.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can also use a winforms textbox, there is an event `TextChanged` that fires after every character typed

Comment: Charles, I am using Console Application as mentioned, not WindowsForms..
I appreciate your answer, but it doesn't help me to know how to do it on another type of project.